# XDebug. Docker. Can't disable an autostart

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm working with `Docker` through the `docker-compose` commands. I want to be able to run my app both in a debug and a normal mode, but now the debugger starts anyway.

I have such an `app.docker` file.

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

WORKDIR /var/www
```

If i click "Run"

[image]

The debug session starts anyway

[image]

I want to be able both to run and debug my tests (and the rest of the app). Do I miss something obvious?

Comment: in the Run menu
"Start Listening for Debug Connections" and "Break at first line of PHP Scripts"

Comment: @lumos0815 Ehm...but it's not starting at the first line)

Comment: @lumos0815 My problem is that I can't prevent XDebug from starting the debug session. Debugger is an additional overhead, so I want to be able to execute my tests both in *debug* and *run* modes.

Comment: if you click "stop listening for debug connections" phpstorm doesn't accept debug connections. to avoid php starting them you could set the xdebug settings via env variables in docker e.g. docker run -e XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM" -e PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=docker-phpunit"

Comment: I want to prevent `php` starting them. Sorry, but I have that settings. Please, check my `app.docker` file again and you will see `idekey` config. And at my `docker-compose.yml` I have `PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=<my-server-name>`

Comment: for starting xdebug - take a look at https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157894/discussion-between-lumos0815-and-d-r).

Comment: @lumos0815 I know how to start XDebug. The problem is that I **can't stop php starting an XDebug session**

Comment: If xdebug tries to debug the script (as that popup suggests) then you may still have "debug me" flag active somewhere in your system. Check `phpinfo()` output -- xdebug specific section (in case it's gets set in another config file) as well as environment variables (if it's set elsewhere using that path). If it's web app -- also check your browser -- it may still have xdebug cookie active. Delete cookies for that site .. or even whole browser (may even try restarting it).

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you for the answer, but I'm woking not via browser, but via phpstorm CLI. I think I've checked everything. `xdebug.remote_autostart=0`. What else should I check. I don't have any cookies or all that stuff, cause it's a CLI.

Comment: Environment variables (mentioned earlier); PhpStorm settings (PHP Interpreter; Run configuration (all fields)). Also check your code for `xdebug_break()`. Unfortunately xdebug does not specify why it tries to connect (what the reason) .. otherwise you would be able to see t in xdebug log. But check the log anyway. Check Docker logs.

Comment: @LazyOne Looks like it's not related to the PhpStorm configuration. I've posted an answer. If you have any new ideas, I'd be glad to hear them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an unexpected xdebug remote host behavior.

I have fixed it with stopping using an environment variable.

In my `docker-compose.yml`

```
app:
        ...
        environment:
            ...
            # removed the line below
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=docker.for.mac.localhost
       ...
```

And added it to the docker file. Something like

```
RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    ... 
    && echo "xdebug.remote_host=docker.for.mac.localhost" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
```

More about it could be read at this [blog post](https://www.larrykagan.com/xdebug-on-docker/). It's creator gave an idea for my solution and we have updated the article.